# Jetty is locking files in sbt

Tags: jetty, lift, sbt

**The problem**

I'm working on a Lift application for work, managed with sbt 0.11.2. I started working on some javascript files that get served by jetty, and found that they are locked once I run `container:start`. This is highly annoying because the lock doesn't go away until I completely exit sbt, but I want to be able to edit my files *while* I see them in the browser.

**What I've tried**

I googled around for a bit and found some old links like http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Fix_file_locking_problem_with_jettyrun but I couldn't get the solution to work for the 'new' Jetty/SBT (where it's `container:run` instead of `jetty-run`). Even more annoying is that the more specific I make my search terms, the less helpful the results become.

Our sbt configuration is done with a *build.sbt* file, and not the full-fledged *build.scala*, and I won't be able to change that. I'm hoping that there's some setting that I can add in to stop Jetty from locking my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deal_with_Locked_Windows_Files

Comment: The "Alternate remedy" mentioned in the link seems to have worked for me.